# Atomic radii for elements as hard spheres

Tags: scattering, atoms, neutrons

In neutron scattering, the atoms in a system are considered as hard spheres. Where could I find the appropriate (reliable) values of the atomic radii consistent with this physical picture? Thank you very much.

Comment: In a very simplified picture the atoms might be considered as hard spheres. In reality it is much more complicated than that. But, at some neutron energy you will have some cross section. Assuming hard sphere scattering one can calculate the apparent 'size' of the nucleus.

Comment: Neutrons don't scatter off atoms, they scatter off the nuclei, so the radius of the atom is irrelevant. Neutrons will interact with electrons via the magnetic dipoles of both, but in a typical neutron scattering experiment the electrons might as well not be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approximation you are referring to is the [scattering length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scattering_length).  Neutron scattering lengths are tabulated in a few places, such as [at NIST](http://www.ncnr.nist.gov/resources/n-lengths/); more elaborate cross-section data is tabulated at the [National Nuclear Data Center](http://www.nndc.bnl.gov/).

Note that the cross section depends on the neutron energy.  Most tabulated cross sections are for "thermal" neutrons with kinetic energy $\frac12mv^2 = k_B\cdot 300\rm\,K = 25\,meV$, since that's what comes out of water-moderated reactors.  In this energy regime most cross sections are proportional to the neutron's "dwell time" near the nucleus, $t \propto \frac1v \propto \frac1{\sqrt E}$, and you'll need to adjust your scattering lengths accordingly.